# How do I list all remote branches in Git 1.7+?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, remote-branch

I've tried `git branch -r`, but that only lists remote branches that I've tracked locally. How do I find the list of those that I haven't? (It doesn't matter to me whether the command lists *all* remote branches or only those that are untracked.)

Comment: You mean you've modified the default refspec, so that `git fetch` and `git remote update` don't fetch all the remote's branches? Because otherwise you could just fetch then use `git branch -r`...

Comment: I must have. `git branch -r` was only showing me remote branches that I had tracked locally. It's working better now.

Comment: `git remote show origin`

Answer (score 1128, accepted):

**For the vast majority<sup>[1]</sup> of visitors here, [the correct and simplest answer to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471827/how-do-i-list-all-remote-branches-in-git-1-7#comment39347566_3472296) "How do I list all remote branches in Git 1.7+?" is:**

```
git branch -r
```

For a small minority<sup>[1]</sup> `git branch -r` does not work. If `git branch -r` does not work try:

```
git ls-remote --heads <remote-name>
```

If `git branch -r` does not work, then maybe as [Cascabel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/cascabel) says ["you've modified the default refspec, so that `git fetch` and `git remote update` don't fetch all the `remote`'s branches"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471827/how-do-i-list-all-remote-branches-in-git-1-7#comment3623773_3471827).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> As of the writing of this footnote 2018-Feb, I looked at the comments and see that the `git branch -r` works for the vast majority (about 90% or [125](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471827/how-do-i-list-all-remote-branches-in-git-1-7#comment39347566_3472296) out of [140](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471827/how-do-i-list-all-remote-branches-in-git-1-7#comment41488609_3472296)).

If `git branch -r` does not work, check `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` contains a wildcard (`*`) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941875/114770)

Comment: You can also do `git ls-remote [url]` so you don't have to clone it first :)

Comment: @Stephan: are you sure about this? `git branch -r`also did not work for me. It's just listing the branches already tracked locally. But `git ls-remote --heads` listed all branches available on the remote repository ...

Comment: @Stephan: looks like you're right, anyway. The comment by nielsbot below resolved this issue for me: _seems this doesn't list all remote branches if I clone from an existing pulled repo and then manually point origin at the git server._

Comment: Looks like if your remote is *origin* you can skip referencing it, as it's the default.

Comment: If one wants to fetch from the branches listed via `git ls-remote` (and not listed at `git branch -r`), one has to execute `git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"` before fetching as described at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26649770/873282.

Comment: Option -r causes the remote-tracking branches to be listed, and option -a shows both local and remote branches.

Comment: Don't forget to do `git fetch --all` before to get all the current remote branches.

Comment: The first part of this answer is wrong. Out of the box without modifying refspec anywhere, `git branch -r` simply does not list all remote branches in all cases. Moreover, because it cannot reliably get all branches, it really shouldn't be trusted in the other "90%" cases either.

Comment: probably a good idea to mention that `git fetch` should be run first right?

Comment: @rexford made a valid point. `git branch -r` tells you at what remote branches your (or just fetched) local branches point at. it does not tell you if they actually exist or not at origin. Yes, it's a common case that it HAPPENS to be the correct list, but not always (for 5 years at 2 jobs I never hit a mismatch).  `git ls-remote --heads` actually lists only existing remote branches.

Answer (score 221):

`remote show` shows all the branches on the remote, including those that are not tracked locally and even those that have not yet been fetched.

```
git remote show <remote-name>
```

It also tries to show the status of the branches relative to your local repository:

```
> git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: C:/git/.\remote_repo.git
  Push  URL: C:/git/.\remote_repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    branch_that_is_not_even_fetched new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    branch_that_is_not_tracked      tracked
    branch_that_is_tracked          tracked
    master                          tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    branch_that_is_tracked merges with remote branch_that_is_tracked
    master                 merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    branch_that_is_tracked pushes to branch_that_is_tracked (fast-forwardable)
    master                 pushes to master                 (up to date)
```

Comment: Exactly.  Not fetched, not tracked locally.

Comment: `branch_that_is_not_tracked      tracked` ?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Yes! `branch_that_is_not_tracked` is a branch that is not tracked by any local git branch. 
However, it has been fetched to the local repository (so there is a remote branch). 
For some strange reason `git remote show` calls this state `tracked`, even though there is no local branch that tracks the remote.
In this case, the opposite of `tracked` is `new`, meaning "not fetched".

Comment: this doesnt work programmatically, too difficult to parse

Comment: This caught a special case I had where I had pulled a remote branch locally which had then been removed on the remote. Then `git branch -r` suggests that there is a remote branch still, but `git remote show origin` shows that `refs/remotes/origin/my-now-dead-branch     stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)`. Much more useful!

Comment: it works good, but impossible to parse in bash to get just branches list

Comment: `git remote show origin` shows stale branches, i.e., branches that do not exist on remote anymore.  Doing `git remote prune origin` deletes the stale branches, and then the output matches what `git branch -r` shows.

Comment: Also, I had to run `git remote update origin` for unclear reasons, before git actually properly pulled all remote branches. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624159/1292652

Answer (score 65):

Using `git branch -r` lists all remote branches and `git branch -a` lists all branches on local and remote.  These lists get outdated though.  To keep these lists up-to-date, run

```
git remote update --prune
```

which will update your local branch list with all new ones from the remote and remove any that are no longer there.  Running this update command without the --prune will retrieve new branches but not delete ones no longer on the remote.

You can speed up this update by specifying a remote, otherwise it will pull updates from all remotes you have added, like so

```
git remote update --prune origin
```

Comment: This fixed my problem - 'git branch -r' now works for me.

Comment: Note to self: `git remote update --prune` is equal to `git fetch --all --prune`

Answer (score 57):

```
git branch -a | grep remotes/*
```

Comment: This is basically equivalent to `git branch -r`, which the OP said wasn't good enough.

Comment: actually both `git branch -a` and `git branch -r` list all remote branches for me, I'm not sure if what the OP said is true. I just setup a test repository and verified this (only had master tracking origin/master but still saw all remote branches with both flags).

Comment: seems this doesn't list all remote branches if I clone from an existing pulled repo and then manually point origin at the git server. The accepted answer handles this case.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to list remote branches created since I last fetched.

Comment: The strange thing: For years I've used `git fetch` followed by `git branch -a`, which only recently started to fail for me. Perhaps git behaviour was changed?

Answer (score 30):

But

`git branch -ar`

should do it.

Comment: Passing in both arguments is redundant. `-r` returns _only_ remote branches. `-a` returns both local _and_ remote branches. Thus, `git branch -a` and `git branch -ar` both yield the same output.

Answer (score 28):

Git Branching - Remote Branches

```
git ls-remote
```

[Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html).

Comment: git ls-remote --heads to get more specific results

Comment: This is the only command that also lists my branch I accidentally pushed without `heads/` in `refs/heads/features/my-branch`, thanks!

Comment: I like this. If you want to filter then you can use grep like this: git ls-remote | grep "your_filter".

Answer (score 24):

You also may do `git fetch` followed by a `git branch -r`. Without fetch you will not see the most current branches.

Comment: `git fetch --all` to have all current branches

Answer (score 16):

Just run a `git fetch` command. It will pull all the remote branches to your local repository, and then do a `git branch -a` to list all the branches.

Comment: `-a`, that was simple!

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way I found:

```
git branch -a
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this...

```
git fetch origin
git branch -a
```

Answer (score 12):

**TL;TR;**

This is the solution of your problem:

```
git remote update --prune    # To update all remotes
git branch -r                # To display remote branches
```

or:

```
git remote update --prune    # To update all remotes
git branch <TAB>             # To display all branches
```

Answer (score 11):

With [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633), you can use:

```
git branch -a
```

Answer (score 9):

The best command to run is `git remote show [remote]`. This will show all branches, remote and local, tracked and untracked.

Here's an example from an open source project:

```
> git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android
  Push  URL: https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    amazon-rc2                   new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    amazon-rc3                   new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    arrivalStyleBDefault         new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    develop                      tracked
    master                       tracked
    refs/remotes/origin/branding stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop merges with remote develop
    master  merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop pushes to develop (local out of date)
    master  pushes to master  (up to date)
```

If we just want to get the remote branches, we can use `grep`. The command we'd want to use would be:

```
grep "\w*\s*(new|tracked)" -E
```

With this command:

```
> git remote show origin | grep "\w*\s*(new|tracked)" -E
    amazon-rc2                   new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    amazon-rc3                   new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    arrivalStyleBDefault         new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    develop                      tracked
    master                       tracked
```

You can also create an alias for this:

```
git config --global alias.branches "!git remote show origin | grep \w*\s*(new|tracked) -E"
```

Then you can just run `git branches`.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have the following branches on a remote repository:
`git branch -a` gives you:

```
*remotes/origin/release/1.5.0
 remotes/origin/release/1.5.1
 remotes/origin/release/1.5.2
 remotes/origin/release/1.5.3
 remotes/origin/release/1.6.0
```

Based on above result command `git branch -rl '*/origin/release/1.5*'` gives you this:

```
 origin/release/1.5.1
 origin/release/1.5.2
 origin/release/1.5.3
```

`-r` stands for remote

`-l` list using `<pattern>`

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer works for me. But I found it more useful to have the commits sorted starting with the most recent.

`git branch -r --sort=-committerdate`

> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Answer (score 6):

I would use:

```
git branch -av
```

This command not only shows you the list of all branches, including remote branches starting with `/remote`, but it also provides you the `*` feedback on what you updated and the last commit comments.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing a mess shell pipeline to get what I wanted. I just merged branches from the origin remote:

```
git branch -r --all --merged \
    | tail -n +2 \
    | grep -P '^  remotes/origin/(?!HEAD)' \
    | perl -p -e 's/^  remotes\/origin\///g;s/master\n//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's a remote branch that you know should be listed, but it isn't getting listed, you might want to verify that your origin is set up properly with this:

```
git remote show origin
```

If that's all good, maybe you should run an update:

```
git remote update
```

Assuming that runs successfully, you should be able to do what the other answers say:

```
git branch -r
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this command,

```
git log -r --oneline --no-merges --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=format:"%n %Cred CommitID %Creset: %h %n %Cred Remote Branch %Creset :%d %n %Cred Commit Message %Creset: %s %n"

CommitID       : 27385d919
Remote Branch  : (origin/ALPHA)
Commit Message :  New branch created
```

It lists all remote branches including commit messages and commit IDs that are referred to by remote branches.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the remote origin you are listing is really the repository that you want and not an older clone.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to get all the branches,

`git fetch --all`

Answer (score 0):

#### What about stale branches?

The other answers don't account for stale branches. Stale branches are references to remote branches that don't actually exist on remote anymore.

The top-voted answer does not return stale branches:

```
git branch -r
```

However, if you run this, you will get stale branches:

```
git remote show <remote>
```

To delete the stale branches, you can do

```
git remote prune <remote>
```

---

#### What if git is not fetching all remote branches?

Sometimes this happens, where `git pull` or `git fetch` does not pull branches from origin.

To fix that, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11623862/1292652). In particular, you might want to run:

```
git remote update <remote>
```

Then when you do `git fetch`, all remote branches will actually be fetched.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624159/1292652