# fetch in git doesn't get all branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

I have cloned a repository, after which somebody else has created a new branch, which I'd like to start working on.  I read the manual, and it seems dead straight easy.  Strangely it's not working, and all the posts I've found suggest I'm doing the right thing.  So I'll subject myself to the lambasting, because there *must* be something obviously wrong with this:

The correct action *seems* to be

```
git fetch
git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD --> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
git checkout -b dev-gml origin/dev-gml
```

At this point there is a problem, for some reason after `git fetch` I can't see the dev-gml remote branch.  Why not?  If I clone the repository freshly, it's there, so certainly the remote branch exists:

```
$ mkdir ../gitest
$ cd ../gitest
$ git clone https://github.com/example/proj.git
Cloning into proj...
remote: Counting objects: 1155, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (383/383), done.
remote: Total 1155 (delta 741), reused 1155 (delta 741)
Receiving objects: 100% (1155/1155), 477.22 KiB | 877 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (741/741), done.
$ cd projdir
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev-gml
  remotes/origin/master
```

I've tried `git update`, `git pull`, `git fetch --all`, `git pretty-please` in all possible permutations...

Comment: What does `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` produce?  If it's not `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, it probably should be.

Comment: yup that's exactly what it produces

Comment: Exactly the same problem, but the comment above solved it! I had `+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` with `master` instead of `*`

Comment: Same problem for me, but none of the suggestions on this page solves it.  Weird.

Comment: I also faced the same problem and seeing Mirkos comment I modified the .git/config section for [remote "origin"], which fixed the problem. Could this have been caused by a shallow clone?

Comment: @thoni56: Yes, this is likely due to a shallow clone.

Comment: I had the same problem and I could not see my colleagues's new created branch when I ran the command `git fetch`; then I decided to just run the command `git checkout my-colleague-new-created-branch` to see if it is really exists or not; then I successfully switched to the branch. In fact, is was there, but it was not shown by `git branch`.

Comment: Could nested submodules result in similar behavior to the shallow clone that's been mentioned?

Comment: I want to add I ran into this issue when I accidently pointed at my fork instead of the actual repo when I created a branch in GitHub

Answer (score 730, accepted):

The problem can be seen when checking the `remote.origin.fetch` setting
(The lines starting with `$` are bash prompts with the commands I typed. The other lines are the resulting output)

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

As you can see, in my case, the remote was set to fetch the master branch specifically and only. I fixed it as per below, including the second command to check the results.

```
$ git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
$ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The wildcard `*` of course means everything under that path.

Unfortunately I saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/git-fetch-doesnt-fetch-all-branches#comment15394706_11623862) after I had already dug through and found the answer by trial and error.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer, as it actually resolved the issue in the original post.

Comment: just a side note, I had to add the `--replace-all` parameter to replace all values on the configuration for my `remote.origin.fetch`

Comment: Note that this can happen if you have cloned your repository with a single branch only, e.g. `git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch [<folder>]`

Comment: Check stux's answer

Comment: This fixed my issue. I have a quick question in case someone would know: Was this (having a master only setting) something from an old version of Git or could that be something that someone setup there deliberately to prevent fetching side-branches? (this master-only fetch setting is on an old machine using an old version of Git)

Comment: This could happen when you clone with `git clone ... --depth 1`

Comment: A shallow clone with `git clone --depth <depth> <repo>` implies `--single-branch`, as noted in the man page [git-clone(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt), so we'd better do it with `git clone --depth <depth> --no-single-branch <repo>`.

Comment: this is how my config looks, but when i do git fetch all it still doesn't pull the remote branch

Comment: `git clone --depth <depth> --no-single-branch <repo>` worked way better for me than fetching all. I was purposely not fetching the entire history and this solution makes it so you'll get the entire history on the next fetch.

Comment: @RubberDuck I'm pretty sure --no-single-branch didn't exist when this was answered in 2014.. Anyway, losing all the history and creating an incomplete clone would not have solved my issue back then. It really depends what you're doing.

Comment: i also had this problem after a shallow clone - as doing `git fetch --unshallow` yes fetches the history, but doestn fetch all the branches :(

Comment: This is the actual solution to the problem : check your remote config and don't shallow clone

Comment: I confirm that this is a fix after you do 
>git clone --depth 1
>git fetch --unshallow
Something I did to fix this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining

Comment: Note: Most hosting providers give you the GUI and from that GUI they mostly fetch the master branch so sometimes in that case we need to update remote origin.

Comment: Happened for me because of `--depth 1` took a while to understand why remote branches are not shown.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem in addition with another answer from @stux which suggests to do `git remote rm origin` then `git remote add origin <git uri>`. This could be maybe added as an edit in your answer to save time for people encountering this problem.

Answer (score 256):

I had this issue today on a repo.

It wasn't the `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` issue as per top solution.

Symptom was simply that `git fetch origin` or `git fetch` just didn't appear to do anything, although there were remote branches to fetch.

After trying lots of things, I removed the origin remote, and recreated it. That seems to have fixed it. Don't know why.

remove with:
`git remote rm origin`

and recreate with:
`git remote add origin <git uri>`

Comment: I had correct git config for `remote.origin.fetch` i.e. `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.
The above solution helped me.

Comment: This solution was the correct one for me also.  This is unfortunate since it indicates there's potentially a bug in Git.

Comment: This also solved my issue. I also appear to have this issue on a machine with git version 2.19.1v but didnt experience it on another machine with git version 2.17.1

Comment: `git remote update origin` worked for me. I guess something needed refreshing?

Comment: `git remote update origin` didn't work for me but removing and adding the remote did.

Comment: I had the same issue. I think it happens when I `git checkout -b myremotebranch` before I `git fetch` the remote branch. It create a new local branch and even after `git branch -d myremotebranch` I cannot fetch it.

Comment: This solved my case too; I just had this issue with git 2.17.1.

Comment: Happened with me (Apple Git-122) git version 2.21.0. Only thing that worked was to remove and then re-add the origin with `git remote add origin`.

Comment: Weird--so it happened again, but as it turns out, though `git branch` doesn't list all the fetched branches, I can still check them out. Seems like some kind of bug.

Comment: This happened to me today with multiple repos, on version 2.25.1.  Noting that we'd recently changed a number of our repos to use 'main' as the primary branch and then deleted 'master'.   On most machines we had no problem with get fetch --all but on my (up-to-date) WSL ubunto instance, consistent with multiple repos.

Comment: Same issue happened to me on `git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)` with an ssh remote. Removing and adding `origin` helped.

Comment: This appeared to work for me (`git fetch` finally printed all the [new branch]es), but then `git branch` still showed that none of those branches were local. I also had to do `git branch <branch_name> FETCH_HEAD` to get `<branch_name>` to appear in `git branch` list locally, and be accessible locally.

Comment: “Try turning it off and on again”

Comment: The solution by @A__ resolved the final issue for me and now I can see the branch locally

Comment: Same for me, this should be added the accepted answered. I encountered the problem with the Git version: `2.41.0.windows.3`.

Comment: same here: removing and re-adding the origin as described in the solution works for me. I'm also on git v 2.17.1

Answer (score 117):

### Remote update

You need to run

```
git remote update
```

or

```
git remote update <remote>
```

Then you can run `git branch -r` to list the remote branches.

### Checkout a new branch

To track a (new) remote branch as a local branch:

```
git checkout -b <local branch> <remote>/<remote branch>
```

or (sometimes it doesn't work without the extra `remotes/`):

```
git checkout -b <local branch> remotes/<remote>/<remote branch>
```

### Helpful git cheatsheets

- [Some notes on git](http://akrabat.com/computing/some-notes-on-git/)
- [Git Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/git-cheat-sheet.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: But my problem is that I can't checkout an *existing* remote branch, because my git client doesn't think it exists.  See my question.  Note that when I run `git fetch` followed by `git branch -a` it does not show all the branches.  I had to delete my working directory and re-clone to see the branch `dev-gml` that a collaborator made.  It worked this time, but we will be branching often!

Comment: Hey @EdwardNewell, thnks for the answer, just to let you know, your link http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/git/ is dead for me...

Comment: It's been a long time since I first asked this question, and I just got pinged because someone posted afresh.  I'm accepting this answer, even though originally nothing actually worked for me.  The reason I have finally marked this correct is because I suspect that what (s)he wrote beside `Edit:` very well might have worked.  It is what I would try if I was still facing the problem.  HTH

Comment: For the record, the bit that helped me here is `git remote update origin`. That made the missing branch visible via `git branch -l -r`. (I did look at `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` and the output was `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` as expected.)

Comment: This answer also worked for me after I saw my git config for `remote.origin.fetch` was correct.

Comment: This worked for me when `get fetch` did nothing .. then I realized I was using an ancient version of git (1.8.x.x), so I'm going to assume the functionality of `fetch` and `remote update` has evolved some in more recent versions. Before this, I had to blow away the repo and re-clone it every time.

Comment: @EdwardNewell Same as you, fetch and checkout tell me not found, re-clone works. Don't know why. :(
git version 2.43.2

Answer (score 30):

Had the same problem today setting up my repo from scratch. I tried everything, nothing worked except removing the origin and re-adding it back again.

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:web3coach/the-blockchain-bar-newsletter-edition.git

git fetch --all
// Ta daaa all branches fetched
```

Comment: This work for me, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

write it from the terminal

```
git fetch --prune.
```

it works fine.

Comment: Thank you! I tried many things and thought I'd just give this a shot... Now to look up what I actually did...

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: It takes all available branches. Look at the head.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, however in my case I could pull/push to the remote branch but `git status` didn't show the local branch state w.r.t the remote ones.

Also, in my case `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` didn't return anything

The problem is that there was a typo in the `.git/config` file in the fetch line of the respective remote block. Probably something I added by mistake previously (sometimes I directly look at this file, or even edit it)

So, check if your remote entry in the `.git/config` file is correct, e.g.:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://[server]/[user or organization]/[repo].git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: I had quite the same case today and think I found a clue. I cloned my repo, as it contains a ´master´ and a ´devel´ branch. When I run `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` it returns `+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`. But at the same time if i look into the config file it shows **two** refspecs `fetch = +refs/heads/devel:refs/remotes/origin/devel` **as well as** `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`. It seems `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` **only returns the last entry**. So, if on doubt look at the file and add the refspec manually.

Comment: At least that is what i get in my enviroment. I'm tied on a windows system, so i use the powershell with the posh-git module installed

Answer (score 6):

I had cloned the repo with --depth 1, so these answers weren't working. What did work for me was

```
git fetch origin BRANCHNAME:BRANCHNAME
```

It succesfully created a local branch with the same name.

Answer (score 5):

`git checkout --track origin/formats` seemed to do the trick:

```
% git branch      ### show local branches
* main

% git branch - a  ### show local and remote branches
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remote/origin/formats
  remote/origin/main

% git checkout --track origin/formats
Switched to a new branch 'formats'
Branch 'formats' set up to track remote branch 'formats' from 'origin'

% git branch
* formats
  main
```

The following should do the same but with different local branch name:

```
git checkout -b my-formats origin/formats
```

A new syntax [`git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/4376643) is available in git c2.23

```
git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

Answer (score 3):

To make it more specific
Create a tracking branch, which means you are now tracking a remote branch.

```
git branch --track branch remote-branch
git branch --track exp remotes/origin/experimental
```

After which you can

```
git branch   # to see the remote tracking branch "exp" created .
```

Then to work on that branch do

```
git checkout branchname
git checkout exp
```

After you have made changes to the branch. You can git fetch and git merge with your remote tracking branch to merge your changes and push to the remote branch as below.

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/experimental  
git push origin/experimental
```

Hope it helps and gives you an idea, how this works.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a face palm moment: if you switch between several clones it is easy to find yourself in the wrong source tree trying to pull a non-existent branch. It is easier when the clones have similar names, or the repos are distinct clones for the same project from each of multiple contributors.  A new git clone would obviously seem to solve that "problem" when the real problem is losing focus or working context or both.

Comment: Thankyou for posting this answer. This was 100% my issue

Answer (score 0):

I had to go into my GitExtensions Remote Repositories as nothing here seemed to be working. There I saw that 2 branches had no remote repository configured. after adjusting it looks as follows[image]

Notice branch `noExternal3` still shows as not having a remote repository. Not sure what combo of bash commands would have found or adjusted that.

Answer (score 0):

My issue: fetch and checkout tell me not found, re-clone works.

`git config --get remote.origin.fetch` output:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Seems no problem.

Because the commit I try to checkout is on a tag but not a branch, I try to
`git fetch --tags`, then checkout the commit, it works finally!

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946840/5281824 to configure git to fetch all branches and tags.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is, apply the following 2 commands:

```
git fetch --all
```

And once you see the branch (which was not visible before e.g. *osc_at_works*), select that and checkout as below:

```
git checkout origin/team/Enterprise/osc_at_works
```

Comment: Didn't work for me!