# Can not fetch all git branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

I've recently installed git on my MacBook for the first time. I generate my ssh key and added it to my git account. I cloned with ssh remote and after cloning I tried to fetch all branches with `git fetch --all` but after running this command nothing happens and I still have just the master branch. Do you think my installation has some problem (my git configuration ) or it is some thing else ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git fetch origin doesn't fetch all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022106/git-fetch-origin-doesnt-fetch-all-branches)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-fetch%5D+all+branches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's the expected behaviour.

Your fetch has retrieved locally all the remote branches as *remote-tracking branches*, but no *local branches* have been automatically created from the get go.

To see remote branches, try `git branch -r`

To create a local version of, say, `development` remote branch, just check it out and it will be created with a default link to its remote counterpart. If you saw `origin/development` in the list generated above with `-r`, just

```
git checkout development
```

and it will then appear in your branch list (without `-r` or `-a`).

Comment: You mean by checking out it makes the branch local ?

Comment: It create a counterpart in the local repo, linked to the remote one by ways of pulling and pushing.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` doesn't change the current branch, it only fetches the information about remote branches. You need to `checkout` a branch to switch to it. Run `gitk --all`, `git branch -r`,  or `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all` to see all the remote branches.

Comment: But at least I can see the branches by running git branch. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes, with `-r` or `-a`.