# How to fetch all remote branch, "git fetch --all" doesn't work

Tags: git, version-control, fetch

I have looked through other questions on similar question.

But they seem to say the answer is  `git fetch --all`.

But in my case, it doesn't work.

This is what I have done for it.

```
> git branch
* master

> git branch -r
origin/master
origin/A

> git fetch --all
> git branch 
* master        #still not updated

> git fetch origin/A
fatal: 'origin/A' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

> git fetch remotes/origin/A
fatal: 'origin/A' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And I also tried `git pull --all` also but the result is the same.

**-------------------Edit-------------------**

```
> git pull --all
Already up-to-date.

> git branch 
* master              # I think it should show branch A also

> git remote show origin
 HEAD branch: master
 Remote branches:
   A      tracked
   master tracked
```

**-------------------Edit-------------------**

```
> git pull origin A
 * branch            A       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

> git branch 
* master                   # I think it should show barnch A also
```

Comment: 1. It's `git fetch origin A` not `git fetch origin/A`. 2. `git pull` will do a `fetch` and a `merge`. `git pull --all` should perform a pull on all **tracked** branches.

Comment: From your edit, it looks like it's working. What's the problem?

Comment: @noahnu I think `git branch` should show `branch A` as well as `master`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git fetch doesn't fetch all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/git-fetch-doesnt-fetch-all-branches)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`git branch` only displays local branches.
`git branch -r` will display remote branches, as you've seen for yourself.

```
git branch
*master

git branch -r
origin/master
origin/A
```

`git fetch --all` will update the list you see when you type `git branch -r` but it will not create the corresponding local branches.

What you want to do is checkout the branches. This will make a local copy of the remote branch and set the upstream to the remote.

```
git checkout -b mylocal origin/A

git branch
master
*mylocal

git branch -r
origin/master
origin/A
```

`mylocal` in this case is `origin/A`. The `-b` parameter will create the branch if it doesn't exist. You could also just type: `git checkout A` will will auto-name the new branch.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're really looking for is the `git branch -a` command. It will show all local and remote branches. Here's an example:

```
# Only show local branches
$ git branch
* master
  develop

# Only show remote branches
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/develop
  origin/foo

# Show both local and remote branches
$ git branch -a
* master
  develop
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/foo
```

You will notice that all of the branches are there - the command will show both local and remote branches.

The `foo` branch only exits on the remote, I don't have a local `foo` branch. To create a local `foo` branch, I would use the `checkout` command:

```
# Create a local 'foo' branch from the remote one
$ git checkout foo
Branch foo set up to track remote branch foo from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'foo'

# Show both local and remote branches
$ git branch -a
* foo
  master
  develop
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/foo
```

This should explain what you're seeing locally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the fetched branch locally as well:

```
git fetch --all && git checkout A
```