# Why am I not seeing git branch after a git fetch?

Tags: git

I have just done :

```
git fetch origin feature/myfeature
```

I would expect to see in my local branches when I issue:

```
git branch
```

But strangely I cannot see the fetched branch, which was successful. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use  `git show-branch --all`?! All detail are here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch

Comment: I made a mistake in fetching. I am now seeing the branch. Thanks to all.

Comment: Not quite fixed I am afraid. I have noted that if I do a fetch, I do not see the branch. When I checkout the branch I then see it. Do you know to checkout to new fetched branch before it become visible?

Comment: I'm not really sure. But can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/git-fetch-doesnt-fetch-all-branches

Comment: Ok, Thanks, will checkout

Comment: Also get Feature/MyFeature-> FETCH_HEAD as opposed to Feature/MyFeature -> Feature/MyFeature which I have seen where it has worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120977/discussion-between-kenny-tai-huynh-and-samjolly).

Answer (score 1):

Because `git branch` shows only local branches. Use `git branch -a` to see both local and remote branches or `git branch -r` to see only remote branches

Answer (score 1):

From git's manual:

> If --list is given, or if there are no non-option arguments, existing
>   branches are listed; the current branch
>          will be highlighted with an asterisk. Option -r causes the remote-tracking branches to be listed, and option
>          -a shows both local and remote branches.

Answer (score 1):

While fetching you can specify a branch that should be created locally

```
git fetch origin <remote_branch>:<local_branch>
```

When fetching, all the branches should be visible when you issue `git branch -a` or `git branch -r`