# How can I synchronize git branches between bare repositories?

Tags: git

I have a bare repository, whose `origin` is on a remote machine.

I would like to download its branches into the local bare repo. I.e. I want to see them with a `git branch -vva` command in the branch list, like so:

```
* master                0bc84f0 [origin/master] something...
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master 0bc84f0 something...
```

In the case of non-bare repos, a `git pull --all` synchronized also the branches (it made the remote branches visible in the local repository), but in the case of a bare repo, pull is impossible.

How can I sync the remote branches in this scenario?

---

Note: `git --fetch` doesn't work, the remote branches are still invisible after it:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git://host/project.git (fetch)
origin  git://host/project.git (push)
$ git branch -vva
* master 4085a31 ...something
$ git fetch
From git://host/project.git
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
$ git branch -vva
* master 4085a31 ...something
```

---

Additional info: my `config` is the following:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git://host/project.git
```

My `config` in a newly cloned (also bare) repo:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git://host/project.git
```

Comment: Problem solved by @Yaba's comments. In 6 hrs he will get the reward. Side-question: it is a git bug or a non-trivial feature?

Comment: See my edit (for addressing the side question)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Solution #1:*

You need to convert your repo to a mirror repo:

```
git remote add --mirror=fetch origin <url>
git fetch
```

A mirror repo will keep to local references in sync with the origin references after a fetch. It has the disadvantage, that a mirror should be an exact copy of the remote repo, what may be not your goal.

---

*Solution #2:*

(Extension from @peterh using the comments):

In the git config (simply `repo/config` in the case of a bare repo), a

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

should exist. If it doesn't, it may be a non-trivial git feature, or a git bug. You can fix it by hand. After that, `git fetch` will work.

Comment: I didn't know this was a thing.  Pretty neat!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, currently I won't convert my repo to a mirror repo.

Comment: The problem with this: mirror-repo is an exact duplicate of the remote side, what is not my intention. I only want to see the remote branches.

Comment: Does your config file have the following entry: `[remote "origin"]
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`? This states to fetch all branches and write them to refs/remotes/origin

Comment: @yaba No, below `[remote "origin"]` is there only an `url = git://host/project.git`. What I find quite surprising, how could it happen. The config still doesn't contain it in the case of a new clone.

Comment: @yaba After inserting this into the config, `git fetch` works, but I suspect now a git bug.

Comment: glad to hear you found a solution. You can still try `git config --global -l` to see if maybe there is something wrong in your global config, which causes the `remote.origin.fetch` to have non-default values.

Answer (score 5):

A `git fetch` should have been enough.

Just for testing, simply try and clone again your bare repo into a new local repo. See then if the remote tracking branches are there.

```
git clone git://host/project.git newproject
cd newproject
git branch -avv
```

> I've did a new clone, and I still can't see any remote branches, despite that the origin points to the correct url.
>   The situation is still the same, as you can see at the end of my question (correct origin URL, but still no remote branches)

That means those remote branches are not in the remote repo in the first place.
The [**default fetch refspec**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)for a clone is

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If the remote repo had any other branches, they would have been cloned as well.

If the config does not show any `fetch` key (as seen with `git config -l`), try and add one:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Check that with:

```
git config --get remote.origin.fetch
```

See more at "[`git fetch` doesn't fetch all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941875/6309)".

---

The true question then becomes: what in the OP's config makes a `git clone` clones only master and include no fetch refspec?

Maybe a [Git environment variable is set](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_environment_variables)?
For instance, [`GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory) (which would include a default config)

Simply adding the fetch refspec does *not* solve the actual issue.
For solving the actual issue, more information is needed (Git version, OS version, ...)

Comment: As you can see at the end of the question, git fetch doesn't work. I've copied the commands and their outputs into the question. Both repos are bare.

Comment: @peterh Yes, hence my suggestion to `git clone` (for testing), not `git fetch`.

Comment: Ok, right! I've did a new clone, and I still can't see any remote branches, despite that the `origin` points to the correct url. The situation is still the same, as you can see at the end of my question (correct `origin` URL, but still no remote branches).

Comment: @peterh That means those remote branches are *not* in the remote repo in the first place. The default refspec (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) for a clone is `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`: if the remote repo has any other branches, they would have been cloned as well.

Comment: @peterh I have edited the answer: can you try and add a `fetch` entry to your `remote.origin` key?

Comment: @peterh just to be clear, I suggested adding the git fetch refspec after seing your config -l: I have added the command to add the fetch section

Answer (score 2):

add to your config in the bare repo the following line :

```
fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
```

your config would then look like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://host/project.git
    fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
```

and then in your repo do

```
git --bare  fetch
```

and new branches will be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` is shorthand for running `git fetch` to synchronize the branch, then `git merge` to merge the local copy with the remote version.

From your bare repo, all you need to do is `git fetch` to sychronize your local branch refs.

See here for more info:  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Comment: `git --fetch` doesn't work. I updated the question. As I understand the doc (thank you very much for the link), it loads only a given remote branch, but not the list of the remote branches.

Comment: When I set up a bare repo, then point it at a full repo and do `git fetch`, it updates my bare repo's remote branch list and looks like this: `* [new branch]      adfsl      -> origin/adfsl` or `38b8475..9bd1033  adff       -> origin/adff`.  Can you post what you're seeing before and after you fetch?

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted the whole scenario into my question.

Answer (score 1):

One would have to start with:

```
git clone --mirror git@host/project.git
```

this creates a bare repo and is ready to receive updates
then cd into your `project.git` and to update your local bare repo:

```
git --bare  fetch
```

Just tested it and works like a charm