# GIT sourcetree - do we need to create local branch to pull new remote branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I have remote branches `origin/master` and `origin/test` on GitBucket server. When I will try to via source tree pull origin/test branch, which is not created locally in my working area on local PC, should I at first create a local branch with name "test" or source tree application will do it automatically?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I did not, in the source tree pull modal window, there is message "Pull into local branch: Master" with no other choices. I think this is because I have no other local branches.

Comment: That will merge the content of that branch into master. To avoid this, and keep them separate, also locally, you would have to create a local branch for it. You can usually do that just by checking out the branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to **Fetch** first

[image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TEICx7yuKpk/VJXgv-Cp9DI/AAAAAAAABXM/wc9ROTgQbZk/s1600/Fetch.png]

Then, as described in "[how to pull remote branch in source tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56803541/6309)", you can *checkout* the remote branch into a local one.

> Expanding `REMOTES > origin` was very close: You need to double click on the remote branch there, in your case **test**.

That will allow to *create* a new local branch based on the remote one.