# Git branches disappeared

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm using git to manage code between my local, dev and master environment.
last night I pushed some data to the master from the dev environment.
Today, when I started my git, it was on the master branch and when I tried to checkout to another branch (local, dev), it gave me the message:

> "error: pathspec 'newLocal' did not match any file(s) known to git".

I also tried to fetch other branches but without any luck.
all I can see, when I try to check the existing branches:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

What should I do?

I also tried reflog, that only show one row.

UPDATE:

I noticed that the git is connecting to a .git library in the main project library (vagrant-joe) instead of connecting to the right library (vagrant-joe/www/joe) even though I am doing "cd ~/vagrant-joe/www/joe/". How can I force it to connect to the right library?

UPDATE 2:
I manage to work it through by reinstalling Git-Bash.
Now I have a new problem - Git does not know my VM's. When I try "vagrant up", I get "A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this command". Vagrant global-status comes up empty. is there anyway to reconnect the VM's to the git?
I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox and Git-Bash.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I tried to checkout to another branch (local, dev)"? What command did you run?

Comment: I have 3 branches (3 local and 3 remote): master, local and dev. I tried to do git checkout dev.

Comment: How did you know that you have 3 branches (3 locals and 3 remotes)? because your git branch -a is telling you that you only have local and remote master branch only. Are you looking at the right remote? `git remote -v`

Comment: I can see all the branches in the correct .git/refs/heads folder. There I can see all the correct local branches

Comment: It seems I can only connect to the main library not to to its subfolders

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch in git doesn't get all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/fetch-in-git-doesnt-get-all-branches)