# Upstream branch shows in local only after a git fetch and not git pull

Tags: git

I learned git pull does a git fetch followed by a git merge

But I create a branch in upstream. The branch reflected in my fork too.

In my local, I did a git pull and did a git branch -a where I did not see that branch.

Only when I did a git fetch I saw the branch in my local.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) mentions:

> More precisely, `git pull` runs `git fetch` with the *given parameters* and calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch.

And those parameters, by default are:

> Default values for `<repository>` and `<branch>` are read from the "remote" and "merge" configuration for the current branch as set by `git-branch --track`.

That involves only one branch, and differs from `git fetch` used directly, which by default uses:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

That is the [usual config setting for a cloned repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941875/6309).