# I can't checkout a branch in Git after fetching branch from remote

Tags: git, version-control

When I do a `git fetch --all`  I can see my branch being fetch from remote it display like this `* [new branch] <branch name> -> origin/<branch name>` and then when I checkout with the command `git checkout <new branch>` nothing happens.

So I checkout from the origin with the command `git checkout origin/<branch name>` but the weird things is that it's saying I'm on different head but I'm still on master branch with a different head? (I'm confused here too).

Actual message:

```
HIT-STORE on master <----- see this im still on master
gco origin/588-feature-message-project-list-view  <---- this is the branch I want to checkout
HEAD is now at 11faa7cb fixes #584: member sign up <-- instead I got this!
```

---

I used to just do this.

1. create a branch in gitlab
2. run command `git fetch --all`
3. `git checkout <new branch>`

That's it, then I have my branch in my local.

---

I also tried doing `git branch --track <new branch> origin/<new branch>` and it will fix it. But next time if I create a new branch I will still get the same problem.

I also tried following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/fetch-in-git-doesnt-get-all-branches)

```
git config --get remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I also tried removing and adding the remote but nothing happens.

---

Here's my Git config too:

[image]

I just added that `ff = only` because I had some warning from Git. if remove that I'll get a warning about pulling.

---

### Update

FYI this is not the same as checking out a branch. I have an issue when checking out a branch.

So when I create a branch on Gitlab I have to do these steps before:

1. `git fetch --all`
2. then git will update my remote origin to have the new branch
3. then I have to simply checkout a branch like what I used to before with the command `git checkout <the_new_brach>
4. and I can work on that branch.

---

This is the problem. I create a branch on Gitlab.

1. do `git fetch --all`
2. then git will update my remote origin to have the new branch
3. Here's the problem part when I do a git checkout `git checkout new_branch`. I will get this error. `error: pathspec 'new_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git`. So I said ok. maybe I need to checkout from origin. so I run the command. `git checkout origin/new_branch` then I get this HEAD error/warning:

```
Note: switching to 'origin/new_branch'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 8a55a856 Merge branch 'hotfix-branch-base1'
```

After getting that error/warning when I run `cat .git/HEAD` I get a SHA:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD                                    
8a55a856dd9a9756533158bf28a98bab81b0d0c6
```

I never encountered that before. now to solve this I have to run the command. `git branch --track new_branch origin/new_branch` every time I checkout the a branch. this is annoying running every time i checkout a branch.

Comment: What happens when you run `git checkout 588-feature-message-project-list-view` ?

Comment: Do you have multiple remotes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: @LeGEC nothing happens. I have to checkout `origin/branch_name` but then it will tell me `HEAD is now at 11faa7cb fixes #584: member sign up `

Comment: @TTT I only have 1 remote branch

Comment: @aRtoo why are you using git fetch --all instead of just git fetch?

Comment: "nothing happens" is weird. What is your active branch after running `git checkout ...` ? `cat .git/HEAD`

Comment: @LeGEC hello sir I added an update. I also remembered updating my git. maybe this is a bug from git? im not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me from your question (before or after the edits) exactly what's *causing the problem*, but here is some background and my own guess:

1. Git has multiple kinds of names: branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and so on.  These names live in [name spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), with branch names technically being names that start with `refs/heads/`.  You can always spell out one of these names completely: `refs/heads/X` means *branch X* and `refs/tags/X` means *tag X*, even if you have a branch and tag that share shortened names.  The name `X` will mean whichever of those it matches: branch X if you only have a branch named X, or tag X if you only have a tag named X.

   In general, humans like to shorten their names.  We see that with names like Robert turning into Bob, Christine becoming Chris, and so on, so this isn't peculiar to Git or computers, even.  But if it's ambiguous—as at a party where everyone is named Bruce—we can always use some longer, unambiguous name, such as Bruce Bruceson.
2. `git checkout` (and, since Git 2.23, `git switch`) will *create* a *new* branch name under certain circumstances.  This creation is referred to as "DWIM mode" internally, with DWIM standing for Do What I Mean (as opposed to what I say).  There is a `--no-guess` option to `git checkout` and `git switch` to *disable* DWIM mode, though it's only properly documented in `git switch` at the moment.  An upcoming Git update will improve the documentation and add a configuration setting to enable or disable guessing by default.

The *certain circumstances* part of item 2 is probably where things are going wrong.  **Before Git version 2.23, you must pay very close attention to this part** because it can destroy work you've done.  This is fixed in Git version 2.23, where Git detects one of these ambiguous cases and warns you to use a more specific command.

(I recommend upgrading if possible.  The work-destroying case is pretty rare, for multiple reasons, but it's also pretty nasty when it happens.  Having Git stop and make you disambiguate your intent is a very good thing.)

#### The circumstances

Suppose you run:

```
git checkout abcd
```

The string `abcd` can be interpreted in four different ways:

- It could be a short version of a *branch name*, especially if you have a `refs/heads/abcd`, which is a branch name by definition as it starts with `refs/heads`.
- It could be a shortened *hash ID*.  The hash ID is the true name of any Git commit, or any internal Git object.  Hash IDs are currently<sup>1</sup> expressed as 40-character hexadecimal strings like [`e1cfff676549cdcd702cbac105468723ef2722f4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1cfff676549cdcd702cbac105468723ef2722f4).  They can be shortened to as few as the first four characters, provided this is unambiguous (and you simply use more characters if it is ambiguous).  Note that branch names that have any character *not* in the [0-9a-fA-F] set *cannot* be misinterpreted this way: the name `beef` might be a shortened hash, but `beer` is definitely not a shortened hash.
- If there's no existing `refs/heads/abcd` and it's not a shortened hash ID, it could be a request to *create* `abcd`, using the guessing DWIM mode.
- Finally, it could be the *name of a file or directory*, or more formally, a *pathspec*, that you wish `git checkout` to extract.  **In my opinion, this is the dangerous case.**  This was one of the reasons that `git checkout` was copied out into two separate commands, `git switch` and `git restore`, in Git version 2.23: `git switch` will *never* interpret `abcd` as this last case; only `git restore` will interpret it this way.

**In the DWIM case** (and only in this case), Git will search through your *remote-tracking names*.<sup>2</sup>  These are the names that begin with `refs/remotes/`.  Your Git copies some other Git's branch names to your own remote-tracking names, so that if they have `master` and `develop`, you wind up with `origin/master` and `origin/develop`, providing that you call the other Git `origin`.<sup>3</sup>  If your Git finds exactly one suitable remote-tracking name, your Git pretends that you wrote:

```
git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

and thus does what you *meant*, rather than what you *said* to do: DWIM!

---

<sup>1</sup>Git is moving towards using SHA-256 instead of SHA-1, and then hash IDs will be 64 characters instead of 40, so as to hold 256-bit numbers instead of 160-bit numbers.

<sup>2</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  They are copied *from* branch names but they do not *act as* branch names, and I find it less confusing to just drop the word *branch* from the name.

<sup>3</sup>Since `origin` is the *default* name for "the other Git" when there's just one other Git, and most people work with one other Git, that's usually the only remote and hence the only set of remote-tracking names: `origin/*`.

---

#### When they don't apply

Your Git *won't* use DWIM mode when:

- There is no remote-tracking name that matches.  There are simply no candidates, so this just can't happen.
- There are two or more remote-tracking names that match.  This can only occur if you have two or more *remotes*, such as both `origin` and `upstream`.

  Suppose you do not have a branch named `beer` and you run `git checkout beer`.  Your Git can't interpret that as a *branch name* because you don't have a branch name `beer`; your Git can't interpret that as a shortened hash ID because `r` is not a valid hexadecimal character.  But you have an `origin/beer`.  That's a candidate for *creating* your own `beer`.  But if you *also* have an `upstream/beer`, well, now you have *two* candidates.  That's too many, and DWIM won't apply.
- *One of the other cases matches first.*

I think this last one is the case that is biting you here.  Let's say you are running `git checkout dev`.  You clearly don't have an existing branch named `dev`, because if you did, you'd get the message about switching to it, and you would no longer be on `master`.  So it's not *that* case.  The letter `v` is not a valid hexadecimal character, and three letters—`dev`—is too short for Git to try it as a shortened hash name, so it's probably not *that* case either.

But what if you have a file, or directory, named `dev`?  Then:

```
git checkout dev
```

is being interpreted as:

```
git checkout -- dev
```

which means *replace the work-tree contents of `dev` (or `dev/*`, if `dev` is a directory) with the contents from the Git's index*.  This functionality is not present in `git switch` as it was put in `git restore` instead, to avoid accidentally clobbering un-`git add`-ed work.

The reason I think it's this case is that if you don't have a branch to check out *and* there's no other match so that Git tries to do the DWIM trick *and* that fails for any reason, then, after DWIM failure, you get an error message.  You are not getting an error message, so the checkout must be succeeding.

#### What to do about it

You have two options:

- Don't use that name.  Branch names are not actually important to Git, so you can use some other spelling.  You might have some sort of outside-of-Git constraint that makes you really want to use that spelling, though.
- Make the command unambiguous.

To make the command unambiguous, you have multiple options:

- Use `-b`, as in [Christoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64268693/1256452).  You can add an explicit `--track`, as in my cut-and-paste from [the `git checkout` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), or `--no-track` if you want the new branch *not* to have an upstream set.<sup>4</sup>
- Use `git checkout --track origin/dev`.  Without the `-b` option, Git will, in effect, reverse the DWIM logic and turn the *remote-tracking name* `origin/dev` (i.e., `refs/remotes/origin/dev`) into the *branch* name `dev` (i.e., `refs/heads/dev`).
- Use `git checkout name --`.  The `--` tells Git that this is definitely *not* a pathspec.  (I'm not a big fan of this particular method, but that's more a matter of taste than anything else.)
- Use `git branch` to create the branch name, then a separate `git checkout`.  This sidesteps all the DWIM stuff as `git branch` always knows that it is dealing with a *branch* name.  The drawback, of course, is that it takes extra steps.
- Use any other multistep method, such as checking out the commit as a detached HEAD followed by `git checkout -b` to create a branch name.

---

<sup>4</sup>I don't know why you might want that, but it's available as an option.

---

#### Why `git checkout origin/dev` results in a "detached HEAD"

Git has two normal operating modes, which Git calls *attached HEAD* and *detached HEAD*.  The detached HEAD mode is really meant for special purpose operations, such as while you're in the middle of an ongoing rebase that requires resolving conflicts manually.  You *can* use it for ordinary everyday work, but that requires a certain minimum of masochism.

In *attached HEAD* mode, Git's special name `HEAD`—which should always be written in all-uppercase like this<sup>5</sup>—is attached to a *branch name*.  Git uses this to enable `HEAD` to find the *current commit* through that branch name, and to automatically *update* that branch name when making new commits.  But because only *branch* names are supposed to automatically update like this, Git won't attach the special name `HEAD` to anything that is *not* a branch name.

The name `refs/remotes/origin/dev`, or any similar remote-tracking name, is simply not a branch name.  (See footnote 2 again.)  Git won't attach `HEAD` to one of these names.  So `git checkout origin/dev`, or anything similar, results in the same detached HEAD mode as `git checkout hash-ID`.  In Git 2.23 and later, the `git switch` command requires that you add the `--detach` option when doing this sort of thing, to make sure you know what you're doing, but `git checkout` just blithely assumes that you know what detached HEAD mode is about, and at most, prints a warning.

---

<sup>5</sup>All-lowercase or mixed spellings like `head` and `HeAd` sometimes work on some file systems, typically on Windows and macOS, at the moment, but there are two problems: a future release of Git may make this stop working at all, and it sometimes *doesn't* work anyway.  If you are in an added work-tree, the lowercase spellings refer to the main worktree's `HEAD`, rather than the added work-tree's `HEAD`.  In any case it's a bad habit to get into.  If you find the name `HEAD` too long, consider using its synonym: the single character `@`.  Since a late Git 1.8 or so version, `@` works everywhere that `HEAD` does.

Comment: hello sir. I tried checking out with the command. `$ git checkout branch_name --` its working but kinda weird because ive never done that before but i guess this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for `git checkout -b new_branch origin/new_branch`.
To ckeck, run

```
git fetch --all
git branch -av
```

Before a checkout, `new_branch` does not exist locally...

Comment: Depending on the version and configuration, it is valid to `git checkout branch-that-only-exists-on-remote` without using `git branch` or `git checkout -b`. Git will look up the branch among the remote references and create the branch locally.

Comment: But git branch should give useful information which he could share.

Comment: before i dont have to do that. I just do a `git fetch --all` then `git checkout branch_name` now i have to checkout with origin `git checkout origin/branch_name` why is that? how can checkout without going to the origin?

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted because the answer itself is correct. There are other correct answers one can give, but this one isn't *wrong*. :-)