# vs code not loading new branches, remote terminal does

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I run following commands in my vs code dev container:

```
git fetch --all
git branch -a
```

I don't see any new branches. Only the master branch and my own created branch.
When I run the exact same commands in a stand alone terminal on mac I do get all my branches.
Could this be something with ssh keys?
I also tried disabling GitLens extension and restarting vscode but that didn't work.

Comment: This fixed my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/fetch-in-git-doesnt-get-all-branches#comment15394706_11623862

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with a VSCode remote SSH session, and it does work.

In your case, it should be related to `git remote -v`: maybe the origin is not set, or different from the same cloned repository on your Mac.

You can also test `git ls-remote` in your remote SSH session repository in VSCode Terminal, to check you can list the remote HEAD SHA.