# git fetch does not fetch a remote branch

Tags: git

Some time ago I `git fetch` a branch from a remote repo.
Let's call it `origin/thebranch`
So I had that and also my local `thebranch`
I checkout a new branch on top of that and did my work
Later I push that new branch into the remote after rebasing it to the latest master

The old `origin/thebranch` stayed in the same place after the rebase

So now I have been told there is new work in `origin/thebranch` so I did `git fetch origin thebranch`.

I got

```
From <remote repo url>
 * branch            thebranch -> FETCH_HEAD
```

and turns out nothing happened
the branch (both remote and local) are in the same place and I did not get the latests commits of "the branch"

What can I do here?

(btw `thebranch` is written by a colleague so I am limited on what I can do I suppose)

Comment: Are you sure the new work is available in the repository that is your `origin`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941875/6330106

Comment: Fetching does _not_ mess up with your local branches. If you want to see your local `thebranch` branch _move_, I guess you will have to either merge/rebase after fetching _or_ do a `git pull` so that it does fetch-then-rebase/merge in a single shot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use git pull command instead of git fetch, to merge remote changes to your local branch. Git fetch will not do the merge part.

`git pull origin thebranch`

Answer (score 0):

The sequence you describe matches what you should see if your local data is already up to date.

---

You can use `git ls-remote` to double check what state the branch is in on the remote server :

```
git ls-remote origin refs/heads/<thebranch>
```

Compare the sha you see here with `git show -s origin/<thebranch>`.