# How can I get remote git branches using Node.js?

Tags: git, node.js, remote-branch

I'm using this awesome library called [Gift](https://github.com/sentientwaffle/gift) to do all of my standard git things (pulling, reading commits, etc). However, I can't seem to get the remote branches. I believe the `git branch -r` command will show me the branches, but the format is certainly not machine-readable:

```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/dev
  origin/gh-pages
  origin/master
```

I'm wondering how I can go about viewing all of the remote branches that a repository has.

Thanks!

Comment: You might like to try `git ls-remote <name>` and filter the output accordingly as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471827/how-do-i-list-all-remote-branches-in-git-1-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show all of the remote repositories for pushing and pulling, try:

`git remote -v`

if you want more information on a specific remote and how it relates to your current repository:

`git remote show <remoteName>`

Answer (score 3):

I guess the command you are looking for is

```
git ls-remote origin
```