# Git fetch does not download remote branches

Tags: git

I cannot get Git to fetch new branches on the remote. `git remote show` will not show that any branch other than master exists, but `git ls-remote` proves that they exist.

Example: `git ls-remote` shows that the branch homodyne_process exist-

```
$ git ls-remote origin
b935ee960a588144d3df0f08a82b81ea705c7543        HEAD
f11bd3ac9c2345a12edb9d49cd5bd027616b2226        refs/heads/homodyne_process
b935ee960a588144d3df0f08a82b81ea705c7543        refs/heads/master
```

Fetch updates and show remote branches

```
$ git fetch
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: gitolite@git.uio.no:***
  Push  URL: gitolite@git.uio.no:***
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master        merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    homodyne_process pushes to homodyne_process (fast-forwardable)
    master           pushes to master           (up to date)
$ git branch -r
  origin/master
```

I managed to get the `homodyne_process pushes (...)` line after running

```
git pull origin homodyne_process:homodyne_process
```

but it still won't show that the remote branch does exist. Why does this happen?

I have also tried any `git fetch origin homodyne_process` and lots of combinations, but the branch `origin/homodyne_process` will not appear.

I am working on windows and the repo is hosted via gitolite.

(I have removed some other branches from the output, for brevity. )

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This answer solved my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941875/1982894.

Basically I needed to run

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

This sets git to fetch all remote branches and not just master. The original configuration was:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how did the configuration become `+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` in the first place?

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately, I have no idea. I don't remember doing anything that should affect that configuration.

Comment: Nasty issue that made me spend an afternoon with endless, cryptic errors, like "merge: origin/master - not something we can merge" and "merge: origin/master - not something we can merge". This solution fixed it! I am including the error strings for posterity, so the next git victims... ehm... users may find the connection and thank both you and me for that

Comment: @Mixopteryx this happend to me when I cloned the repository with --depth; apparently this happens also if you use --single-branch while cloning