# Unique git url for github repo with multiple branches?

Tags: python, git, github

I'm looking at a flask app which I would like to import into an openshift project (https://github.com/lpolepeddi/intro-to-flask) . This contains a a series of 'checkpoints'(branches) as part of a tut. I want to grab the final code which is at https://github.com/lpolepeddi/intro-to-flask/tree/20_visibility_control for the starting point of a project . Is the a way to get a unique git url for this branch of the form

```
https://github.com/lpolepeddi/intro-to-flask.git
```

So that I can pull it in with a command like:

```
 git remote add upstream -m master https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-openshift-quickstart.git
```

Comment: Git doesn't have a concept of "checkpoints". Perhaps you mean branches?

Comment: Sorry they refer to it as checkpoints in the article and the repo https://github.com/lpolepeddi/intro-to-flask/tree/20_visibility_control but you are right they are branches

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471827/how-do-i-list-all-remote-branches-in-git-1-7

Comment: I understand the desire to clone only a particular branch, but your `git remote…` command confuses me. What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Answer (score 3):

Although as far as I know "single branch GitHub url" doesn't exist, you could just clone entire repo and later change branch:

```
git clone https://github.com/lpolepeddi/intro-to-flask.git
cd intro-to-flask
git checkout 20_visibility_control
```

or as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30588132/2351523), clone only one branch:

```
git clone --branch 20_visibility_control --single-branch https://github.com/lpolepeddi/intro-to-flask.git
```