# git command to change the repository and want clone too on local

Tags: git, github, branch, clone

Before start I want to tell you scenario. I have created gitlab account and uploaded three different projects. when I am using browser to see all branches I can see: a) master b)feature/bakend c)frontend but when I am running command from command prompt
git branch
* master

Now I am using another laptop (that soes not have local backup) and when I am doing clone operation it is creating local repository for one project only, then can you please tell me how should I clone my another projects? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all remote branches in Git 1.7+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471827/how-do-i-list-all-remote-branches-in-git-1-7)

Comment: I hope you are on your master branch, seems like your local repository is not up to date with the master, try this: git fetch, it will update your local repo with the remote and after that execute git branch -a, it will show you the rest of the branches available in remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you meant was you have a single repository with **three** different branches and you just want to be able to go to these three different branches in your newly cloned repository. This should be fairly simple.

Here is a general workflow:

```
git clone <your_repository_url>
```

This will download your remote repository to your local computer.

```
git status
```

This will show the current status of the repository including which branch you currently are.

```
git branch
```

This will list all the branches that are there within the repository. The branch name with '*' at the front is the one you are currently at. You should see all the branches you saw via the browser in the gitlab remote repository.

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

This will help you move between branches. Eg if you want to move to **frontend** branch simply run :

```
git checkout frontend
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: git push origin frontend                                                         
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: can you please tell me how could I change my current project repository to another project. I mean how I clone the another project

Comment: @ArunaPatil 
To clone another project, just run 'git clone <another_project_url> in commandline in the directory you want the project to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're listing local branches, your branches currently only exist on the remote. You can use the `checkout` command to checkout a branch in the repository that doesn't have a local branch yet:

```
git checkout feature/bakend
```

Comment: git checkout feature/bakend
error: pathspec 'feature/bakend' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: How is this answer different from the one accepted? :D Did you mis-spell your branch name, perhaps?