# regexp - grep origin/<branch-name> except origin/HEAD

Tags: regex, bash

I want to write a bash script that scans the branches in my repository, checkout them one by one and fix a typo in every source using sed.

My problem is to make a list of the branches with origin/HEAD filtered out.

```
branches=$(git branch -r | grep 'origin/^(HEAD)+')
```

Code inspired by this answer: [Regex - Does not contain certain Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters)

But I got an empty list in $branches.

Comment: The caret operator only means inverse for a character class like `[^a-z]`, not for parentheses. Maybe you want the `grep -v ` flag?

Comment: Also, just a hunch, but if you are trying to automate the application of a change across a bunch of branches, you might look at `git cherry-pick` or `git apply`. It might easier to apply a single commit or diff that way instead of sed'ing and committing repeatedly in a script.

Comment: On the off-chance your `git branch -r` isn't returning all the branches you need, there's a SO [thread on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471827/how-do-i-list-all-remote-branches-in-git-1-7/3472296).

Comment: @xdhmoore, git branch -r dose indeed return all of my branches. The problem is when iterating over $branches I get the values "origin/HEAD" and "->". I dont want to apply git checkout on those, so was hoping to filter it out using grep.

Comment: @xdmoore, thanks for pointing out git apply and cherry-pick. Im gonna read more about those, see how can I use them.

Comment: This would exclude `origin/HEAD` using `git branch -r | grep -vF origin/HEAD`. But you should not assign a list to a string variable. Use an array instead. See: [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64734414/7939871).

Answer (score 3):

Get git remote branches into a Bash array:

```sh
read -r -d '' -a branches < <(
  git \
    branch \
    --list \
    --remotes \
    --format '%(refname:lstrip=-1)' |
      grep -vF HEAD
)
```

Comment: Indeed, I tried branches=$(git branch -r | grep -vF 'HEAD') to see it kinda did the trick the short way. The read command on the other hand results in a 'Syntax error: "(" unexpected'. Another puzzle for me to solve...

Comment: @Zack this is Bash code, so it will fail with zsh or ksh

Comment: finally solved. needed to call "bash my_script.sh" instead of "sh my_script.sh". And they said Ubuntu is user friendly...